# toast message displayed at specific frames

Tags: android, frame, android-toast

I want toast messages to start in my android application at specific frames in my animation.  Below I have posted the xml file which stores my frames.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >


<item android:drawable="@drawable/sy1" android:duration="210" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sy2" android:duration="210" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sy3" android:duration="210" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sy4" android:duration="210" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sy5" android:duration="210" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/sy6" android:duration="210" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to show a toast message at 4th frame. Calculate the time to show the toast using `animationDrawable.getDuration(int i)`.

```
int STARTING_FRAME = 4;
int totalTime = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < STARTING_FRAME; i++) {
  totalTime =+ animationDrawable.getDuration(i);
}
```

Now, as soon as you start the animation, show a toast using `handler.postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`.

```
animationDrawable.start();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Toast text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}, totalTime);
```